# What are the correct version numbers for Swift - Obj-C to use Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have now Xcode 8 and I know it uses Swift 3.0. But I don't know this: which versions of Swift and Obj-C versions are installed?

I have old project building with Obj-C in 2012 but, which Xcode version do I need to complete it, so I get zero warnings?

Where can I see date to Obj-C and Swift versions with working true Xcode versions?

My client wants edit project little changes but when I open it in Xcode 8 gives me many many errors. (My projects not have any error warning in Xcode 6).

And so to change only `titlecolor` built Xcode6 project, I need to fix 100 more warnings in Xcode 8? Is that not silly?

Comment: Xcode 8 compiles Obj-C as well

Comment: @user3351949 yeah but gives me many errors for xcode 8

Comment: @user3351949 my client dont want to update it but when i open it with xcode 8 gives me many errors ?

Comment: You have to update the `ObjC` or `Swift` project. From your name I hope you have knowledge of both. Its for the better of you and your customers.

Comment: it gives you all that errors probably because of the SDK used in project are deprecated or completely changed since 2012.

Comment: @New16 yeah but i want to change only example title color but i need to change 100 more warning  :|

Comment: Yeah, it was easy if you have done this process as the iOS released different iOS versions. Now, I know the pain of working with the warnings and errors. Take time and do it.

Comment: Objective-C is quite "Stable". If XCode gives your warnings, it's because of the API (deprecated usually or removed). The issue with Swift is that it wasn't stable, and had too many changes in "the language itself" and the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode):

> Xcode 4.3, released on February 16, 2012, is distributed as one application bundle, Xcode.app, installed from the Mac App Store. Xcode 4.3 reorganizes the Xcode menu to include development tools.[23] Xcode 4.3.1 was released on March 7, 2012 to add support for iOS 5.1.[24] Xcode 4.3.2 was released on March 22, 2012 with enhancements to the iOS Simulator and a suggested move to the LLDB debugger versus the GDB debugger (which appear to be undocumented changes). Xcode 4.3.3, released in May 2012, featured an updated SDK for Mac OS X 10.7.4 "Lion" and a few bug fixes.
>
> Xcode 4.4 was released on July 25, 2012. It runs on both Mac OS X Lion (10.7) and OS X Mountain Lion (10.8) and is the first version of Xcode to contain the OS X 10.8 "Mountain Lion" SDK. Xcode 4.4 includes support for automatic synthesizing of declared properties, new Objective-C features such as literal syntax and subscripting, improved localization, and more. On August 7, 2012, Xcode 4.4.1 was released with a few bug fixes.
>
> On September 19, 2012, iOS 6 and Xcode 4.5 were released. Xcode added support for iOS 6 and the 4-inch Retina Display on iPhone 5 and iPod touch 5th generation. It also brought some new Objective-C features to iOS, simplified localization, and added auto-layout support for iOS. On October 3, 2012, Xcode 4.5.1 was released with bug fixes and stability improvements. Less than a month later, Xcode 4.5.2 was released, with support for iPad Mini and iPad with Retina Display, and bug fixes and stability improvements.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean with Swift - obj-c. You can still build apps with Objective-C in the Xcode 8 version and you can also open old Objective-C code with Xcode 8. The only thing that happens, is that Xcode will ask you to what new device the storyboard needs to change.

If you want to work with Swift 2.2 for some reason and you don't want to change that code to Swift 3.0, you can download the old Xcode 7.3.1 from the [Apple](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.3.1/Xcode_7.3.1.dmg) site here and work with your code that is still in Swift 2.2.

I would not recommend to continue to work with Swift 1.2.